# CollectionView weird scrolling when is used in TabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview

I'm using a collection view in one TabBarController, but the vertical scrolling with  smoth-interruption.
I'm using a nib files for this project.

This happen only when I use collectionView in TabBarController.

[image]

Comment: Could you please add more information, like images, to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more context to your question, but I have found a great way to improve collectionview performance is to rasterize the cells, which is to basically cache them as a bitmap image so they aren't constantly rendering while the user is scrolling. You can do that with the following code:

```
cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

If this doesn't help, I would check that the other view controllers in the tab bar arent doing and tasks that would block the main thread. If they are, you should stop these tasks in their "viewDidDisappear" methods.

You can check for processes running on the main thread by placing the following code in various places.

```
NSLog(@"thread: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
```

if your output looks something like this:

```
thread: <NSThread: 0x15d608a20>{number = 1, name = main}
```

then the code is running on the main thread. Usually you want to reserve the main thread for code that is directly related to updating the UI. You should put this log statement in the other view controllers and see which ones are firing while you are attempting to scroll the collectionview, then that is what is causing the choppy performance.

Comment: thnx for response, this bug happen just when i use collectionview in tabbarcontroller, in other scenarios works fine.

Comment: Are the other viewcontrollers in your tab bar doing a lot of processing? Your main thread could be locking up due to other processes, which would cause a UI lag. I updated my answer with more info

Comment: cane u give one example how to stop tasks in viewDidDisappear method @RDSpinz